# How can I eliminate warning NETSDK1137 in a .NET 5 WPF program?

Tags: wpf, .net-5

I have the following warning in a WPF program that used to be built for .NET Framework 4.5 but is now being built for .NET 5.

```
Warning NETSDK1137  It is no longer necessary to use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK. 
    
Consider changing the Sdk attribute of the root Project element to 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'. 
    
ListEditor 

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   376
```

Clicking the warning opens the file `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets` at line 376. This file starts with a comment that says `DO NOT MODIFY`.

```
<!--
***********************************************************************************************
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets

WARNING:  DO NOT MODIFY this file unless you are knowledgeable about MSBuild and have
          created a backup copy.  Incorrect changes to this file will make it
          impossible to load or build your projects from the command-line or the IDE.

Copyright (c) .NET Foundation. All rights reserved. 
***********************************************************************************************
-->
```

Line 376 falls in this XML element...

```
  <Target Name="_CheckForUnnecessaryWindowsDesktopSDK"
        BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform"
        Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and $([MSBuild]::VersionGreaterThanOrEquals($(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV), '5.0')) and '$(_MicrosoftWindowsDesktopSdkImported)' == 'true' and '$(TargetFrameworks)' == ''">
    <NETSdkWarning ResourceName="UnnecessaryWindowsDesktopSDK" />
  </Target>
```

There is a Project element that encloses the entire file. The element is this...

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    ...omissions...
</Project>
```

Since that element does not mention `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK` the Project element does not seem to be the point at which the replacement `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` should be placed.

How do I eliminate the cause of this warning?

Comment: [NETSDK1137: Don't use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1137)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

*Your* project, the `.csproj` file, not the MsBuild target xml. Change the top line to the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

Answer (score 16):

This happens when you port the old project to .Net 5.

Perform a search of `Project Sdk=` to open your `.csproj` file,
and correct the 1st line to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`.

This should fix the warning.